# How can i interact with my contract i deployed on rinkeby network and send eth to uniswap

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, rinkeby, truffle-deployment

[image]

I am practicing using the uniswap v3 router and i created a simple contract that attempts to swap a certain amount of ETH to dai. This is the function that does so

```
function convertETHToDAI() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "You must send ETH");
    uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 15; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    address tokenIn = WETH9;
    address tokenOut = multiDaiKovan;
    uint24 fee = 3000;
    address recipient = msg.sender;
    uint256 amountIn = msg.value;
    uint256 amountOutMinimum = 1;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;

    ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams(tokenIn,
    tokenOut,
    fee,
    recipient,
    deadline,
    amountIn,
    amountOutMinimum,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96);
    uniswap = IUniSwapRouter(UniswapAddress);

    uniswap.exactOutputSingle{value: msg.value}(params);
    uniswap.refundETH();

    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "Refund to caller failed");
}
```

I deploy it successfully to the rinkeby test network and try to call it and send ether with the truffle console and all i get is the

> evalmachine.:1
> await engine.convertETHToDAI{value: 0.1 ether}()
> ^
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

error shown in the image.

I am certain i am doing something wrong but i dont know what.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just the syntax:

```
await engine.convertETHToDAI({value: 0.1 ether})
```

Comment: it fails with this error   evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
  await engine.convertETHToDAI({value: 0.1 ether})
                                           ^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Then it remains to convert ether to wei
await engine.convertETHToDAI({value: 100000000000000000})